# How to reduce spam

Tags: spam

I installed WordPress along with a few add-ons to combat spam. Both are for registered and non-registered members posting comments. I added a standard Captcha as well as a mathematical challenge question (5 + what = Eleven). I have tried different Things and software, but the result is the same. I receive daily spam emails.

It serves the spammer no good, as I review all comments, but that does not stop comments.

Do spammers now have humans go to the same website daily and try to just sent out spam (unlikely) or is it just a software program. In the latter case, why is the WordPress add-ons not stopping spam comments.

Do others have the same issue? Did I miss something, when setting up WordPress?

Comment: did you tried using any spam protection plugin like [akismet](http://wordpress.org/plugins/akismet/) or [antispam bee](http://wordpress.org/plugins/antispam-bee/)?

Comment: Of the plug-ins that I am using, akismet, is one of my plug-ins. The others being Akismet, Captcha (BestWebSoft), Growmap Anti Spambot Plugin, SI CAPTCHA Anti-Spam, yaCAPTCHA. Akismet and Captcha are the two that show.

Comment: Wow. Install this and ditch every one of those plugins, except Akismet: http://www.wordpress.org/plugins/spammers-suck and share how it works for you here, so it can help others.

Comment: Of course, but received warnings: Warning: file_get_contents(./templates/wp-admin/option-row.tpl) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in .\wp-content\plugins\spammers-suck\includes\functions.php on line 382
Warning: file_get_contents(./templates/wp-admin/opt-in.tpl) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in .\wp-content\plugins\spammers-suck\includes\functions.php on line 382

Comment: I had to deactivate the control, as the warnings show on the live site as well.

Comment: The BestWebSoft captcha was defeated around May 2013, so it offers no longer any protection against the spam bots, unfortunately. For other captchas i guess it's similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use these three plugins in combination:

- [Cookies for Comments](http://wordpress.org/plugins/cookies-for-comments/)
- [Simple Trackback Validation](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-trackback-validation/)
- [Akismet](http://wordpress.org/plugins/akismet/)

Ditch the captcha and math plugins, they're pretty much useless. The combination of these three is enough for most anybody, without having to put any problems back on the user.

Comment: Ok, I added these plug-ins, so we shall see what happens. For posterity, here is the complete list:  Installed and Activated [Akismet, Cookies for Comments, Simple Trackback Validation], Installed Not Activated [Blog Protector, Impostercide], Installed and Impossible to Activate [Spam Hammer 1-Series]

Comment: Just check Akismet license. It isn't free AFAIK.

Comment: Akismet is free for personal use, as it states here: http://akismet.com/about/

Comment: I held off posting my comment or accepting an answer to see how things went, and so far as of this comment, I have had no further spam, so I guess the suggested answer is correct.

Comment: Update: The above answer did not reduce spam. I still receive hundreds of spam email messages per whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Spammers becomes smarter. If you want to fight with them you must have to be more smarter than a Spammers.

I recommend you to use The 2 Free WordPress plugin and a little tweak your WordPress settings:

1. Akismet
2. [AVH First Defense Against Spam](http://wordpress.org/plugins/avh-first-defense-against-spam/)

As you know that, WordPress is the most advanced Blogging Platform and It has some advanced configuration to fight with Spam. You can configure discussion settings from Settings > Discussion. Here you will find various option about commenting and prevent spammers.

You can also paste the following lines to your .htaccess, It will dramatically reduce spam comments to your WordPress:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Hope this will reduce spam comments to your WordPress :)

Answer (score -3):

Best way to reduce spam is point of entry which is at the user registration.  If you stop bots there then you will reduce a lot of spam.  A neat little plug-in that has come out for wordpress is [No More Captchas](http://nomorecaptchas.com) which uses [bio-chronometric technology](http://oxford-biochron.com) which uses type, click, or touch as a means of security.  It will determine if you are a human or bot.  There is a free version too. Jumbled up words and several re-entry's are a thing of the past.

Comment: Now I see why I am inundated with comments. The previous stuff that I did (first answer) yielded no restrictions on comments. I added the more captchas, but that do anything visible. I added BotDetect Captcha and that for two of my blogs gave a nice captcha, but interestingly enough not for the 3rd one. We shall see what happens in the next few days.

Comment: If you're going to post about your own product, please make it clear that you are doing so. Otherwise it seems a little... spammy. (Ironically.)

Comment: I'm just trying to give some advise from the question which mentioned "How to Reduce Spam".  Simple fact, captchas are a waste of time and don't work at reducing spam.

Comment: That's fine. However, a simple change of wording -- eg, from "A neat little plug-in that *has come out* for wordpress is No More Captchas" to "A neat little plug-in *that I wrote* for wordpress is No More Captchas" -- would make it plain that you're offering a product that might help the OP. A simple disclosure like that makes it look much less spammy, IMO.